# Excluded get method with middleware function

Tags: node.js, express

I use the middleware function for intercept my client request ( http://localhost:8080), for load and receive statics files from a public folder.
How to do for use next parameter for not excluding my get method that it permit to stamp a message into a console? Thanks at all

```
var express = require("express");
var app = new express();


app.use("/",express.static(__dirname + "/Application/public"));
app.use("/admin", express.static(__dirname + "/Application/admin"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    console.log("I send your public project");
});

app.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: I'd recommend you update the path for static files to `/public` or `/static` etc. Alternatively, you can write a wrapper for `express.static` which triggers the `next()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you show me an example if is possible? Thank you very much

Comment: You might be resetting `"/"` when you call it the second time, although I have no idea why.

Comment: Deleting "/" on the path function middleweare, to default express map with generic path "/".